# Make sure all threads exited

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

In a win form application, I have an array of threads which are started like this:

```
bool stop = false;
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];

for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
    threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Job));

// How to make sure all threads have exited, when the boolean = false

void Job()
{
    while (!stop)
        // Do something
}
```

Now if user press STOP, the boolean value for `stop` will set to true, so threads exit the `Job` method one after another. How can I make sure all threads are exited?

**NOTE:** I need traditional threading for my case and `TaskLibrary` doesn't fit my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought about using [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead?  You said "traditional threads"..I'm not exactly sure what you mean so I don't know if this is a valid proposal or not, but here it is anyways in case `Join()` doesn't solve your problem

```
BackgroundWorker[] workers = new BackgroundWorker[10];
bool allThreadsDone = false;

// initialize BackgroundWorkers
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        workers[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
        workers[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        workers[i].RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        workers[i].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(AlgorithmsUI_DoWork);
        workers[i].RunWorkerAsync();
}

// thread entry point..DoWork is fired when RunWorkerAsync is called
void AlgorithmsUI_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      while (!stop)
            // do something        
}

// this event is fired when the BGW finishes execution
private void  worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    bool threadsStillRunning = false;
    foreach (BackgroundWorker worker in workers)
    {
        if (worker.IsBusy)
        {
            threadsStillRunning = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!threadsStillRunning)
        allThreadsDone = true;
} 

protected override OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
         if (!allThreadsDone)
         {
              e.Cancel = true;
              MessageaBox.Show("Threads still running!");
         }
}
```

This should prevent your form from closing if any threads are still running.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Join method to check if all threads have stopped.

```
 foreach (var t in threads)
 {
     t.Join();
 }
```

Comment: Where to put this code? This is a win form application and UI thread has been released after creating new threads.

Comment: If the UI has been released then why worry?  But seriously, I would place it in method that handles the stop button being pressed.

Comment: I want to disallow program exit until all threads are exited. If user closes main form and there are some active threads in task manager, user feels, application has failed (although all threads will exit after a while)

Comment: Where to put this `foreach` ?

Comment: Ok, then place the code in your Main method; after the Main form returns.

Comment: @Xaqron: You put this code at the place where you want to make sure that all threads have finished.

Comment: I personally think, that it's better to let the application be invisible for the time it takes it to shut down properly and let it appear in the task manager, than tell user "You can't close this application right now, because it's still working" Only a few users will actually go and check in the task manager if the process is still there. On the other hand every single user will be annoyed that they can't close the app. They will be asking, why, oh why, can't you close the damn form an let it finish up whatever it needs to finish up invisibly?

Comment: You have some code that sets stop to true - put this code there. On in main form OnClosing event. The only problem, it will make your app hang until the threads quit.

Comment: @zespri: This is not a console application. I cannot block UI thread until all threads join (also `stop` will never set to `true` if UI thread blocks). I knew what is `Join`. This solution doesn't fit my scenario.

Comment: @Xaqron: Your question was  **How can I make sure all threads are exited?**  And I have answered it.  Perhaps you should ask a question that fits your scenario!

Comment: @Xaqron: "I cannot block UI thread until all threads join" I'm not suggesting you block UI. You want to make sure that all threads exited. Answer *when / where* you want to make this sure. Then you'll know where to put the code.

Comment: @zespri: its not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's a simple solution I used back in .NET 3.0 to make sure a large but deterministic number of threads had completed before continuing:

Global:

```
AutoResetEvent threadPoolComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
static int numThreadsToRun;
```

As you activate the threads:

```
numThreadsToRun = [number of threads];
[start your threads];
threadPoolComplete.WaitOne();
```

At the end of each thread's code:

```
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numThreadsToRun) == 0)
{
   threadPoolComplete.Set();
}
```

Comment: + This is a good example for non win form similar tasks. For win forms,as `alexD` stated, async background worker is easier to implement.